# Comments in android(Java/XML) code will affect the size of APK?

Tags: java, android, xml, comments, apk

I just want to know if Comments in android(Java/XML) code will affect the size of APK?

example:-

```
/*ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: yes i'm doing research on that. But i'm expecting if someone could explain me on that.

Answer (score 7):

Commented code is not included in the compiled ode.

Answer (score 2):

No, the comments are removed before the class file is created. The compiler is responsible for removing comments and them are not included in the final files.

Just try to create a class file with coments and then use any decompiler to check the .class file.